# Is it available that , Can i download simulator/emulator separately to test metro app?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

i am  developing an metro app ,

i wanted to know is there a way  that  we can  download a emulator/simulator separately for win8 metro app testing ??

so that it would be easy for my testing team to test my application instead of having the entire development environment like vs2012 or win 8 OS ??

if i am not wrong  it works that way  in Android where we can download the emulator separately and test it.

if it works in android why not windows , that is the reason i asked this question.

i request you to correct me if i am wrong .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have Windows 8 (the operating system) to be able to test Windows Store apps. In contrast to Android where you need to emulate the hardware for Windows Store apps you already have the required hardware (i.e. your x86/x64 computer) and only need the operating system.

Taking this into account the current situation is as follows:

- You need Visual Studio 2012 (Express for Windows 8 or any non-free version) installed on Windows 8 to develop Windows Store apps.
- You can only run Windows Store apps on Windows 8, but don't necessarily need Visual Studio 2012 installed. It's enough to have an active developer license on the machine to be able to install Windows Store app packages created by Visual Studio. You can also install [Remote Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#remote-tools) to enable remote debugging.
- You could install Windows 8 (even the [90 days trial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx)) on a virtual machine and test (and potentially even develop) your applications there.
- The only simulator or emulator available is part of Visual Studio 2012. From it you can choose to debug your application in the simulator (in the background it makes a remote desktop connection to your machine) which allows you to test Windows 8 specific features (touch, gestures, location, rotation etc.) even without having a computer capable of them.